# Append values to a file in R invoking shell commands

Tags: r, append, rscript

I am looping to run an Rscript on linux 40 times. Each time it runs, it generates few statistics which I should append to file. The file should have a table of all the statistics appended 40 times. This is my code:
 `mean_data <- mean(m)`
`minimum <- min(m)`
 `maximum <- max(m)`
 `standard_daviation <- sd(m)`
 `Range <- range(m)`
 `file <- "map1"`
 `x <-data.frame(file, mean_data,minimum,maximum,Range,standard_deviation)`
 `system2("echo", args = paste0(" ", x ," >> tab_1.txt" ))`

The expected result is:
 `file mean_data minimum maximum Range standard_deviation`
`[1] map1 1349 1100 1600 500 45`
`[2] map2 1242 1291 1628 337 38`

But the result was:
`[1] 1349 1100 1600 500 45`
`[2] 1242 1291 1628 337 38`

Using write.table is not a good option for me because I will not be able to append the values each time. 
I am running the script with the above code in shell through a loop 40 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append=TRUE` in `write.table`.

> `append`
>
> logical. Only relevant if file is a character string. If TRUE, the output is appended to the file. If FALSE, any existing file of the name is destroyed.

```
df <- data.frame(file, mean_data,minimum,maximum,Range,standard_deviation)
if(!file.exists("filename.txt")) {
    write.table(df, "filename.txt", col.names=TRUE)
} else {
    write.table(df, "filename.txt", col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
}
```